# Get specific attribute on magento category view.phtml

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to create a [Asos](http://www.asos.com/Women/Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=8799) style header on my Magento category page.

In this box I have pulled in the category title and the category description, I am also some how needing to pull in a specific attribute from the layered navigation into the category view.phtml page.

At the moment I have

`<?php $prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$att = $prod->getResource()->getAttribute('product')->getFrontend()->getValue($prod);
echo $att;
 ?>`

But it is just pulling in the word `No` instead of the attributes that it is showing in the layered navigation for this specific category.

Comment: You are getting the `value` of attribute which is `No`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);
```

Thanks to [@Daniel Kocherga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1051445/daniel-kocherga) for the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924226/magento-product-attribute-get-value).

Comment: I have just changed it to that but now nothing is being pulled in should it just be `<?php Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'product', $storeId); ?>` or should I have to echo it as well somehow?

Comment: That dosen't seem to have made a differnace I now have `<?php echo Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'product', $storeId); ?>` any more ideas? I am using 1.7.0.1 if that helps.

Comment: I though I had to change 'attribute_code' parameter to the attribute that I want to show a list of? I have changed it back but still nothing is showing?

Comment: yes you are correct, i just didn't see it in the code you posted, i'll try to look in to this soon :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15674/discussion-between-pzirkind-and-matt)

Answer (score 0):

From code/core/mage/catalog/block/product/view/attributes.php

```
   public function getAdditionalData(array $excludeAttr = array())
    {
        $data = array();
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
//            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
            if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && !in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $excludeAttr)) {
                $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

                if (!$product->hasData($attribute->getAttributeCode())) {
                    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('N/A');
                } elseif ((string)$value == '') {
                    $value = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No');
                } elseif ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
                    $value = Mage::app()->getStore()->convertPrice($value, true);
                }

                if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
                    $data[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = array(
                        'label' => $attribute->getStoreLabel(),
                        'value' => $value,
                        'code'  => $attribute->getAttributeCode()
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Pretty sure this is the responsible section for displaying a 'No' or 'N/A' with your attributes

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but see below URL. I think it is help full to you.

**How to add attributes to product grid in category**

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/add-attributes-to-product-grid

**Magento Attributes: Using Different Filterable Attributes Per Category**

http://www.human-element.com/Blog/ArticleDetailsPage/tabid/91/ArticleID/68/Magento-Attributes-Using-Different-Filterable-Attributes-Per-Category.aspx

**Get Data for Magento Category Attribute on Product Page**

http://spenserbaldwin.com/magento/get-data-for-new-magento-category-attribute

Comment: see also Hide Attribute In Specified Categories http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/215030/#t296077

Comment: read it http://www.netismine.com/magento/get-sort-category-children-as-collection

Comment: read it http://www.imagedia.com/2010/02/how-to-add-attributes-to-product-grid-or-list-view-in-category-in-magento-commerce/