# Using event sales_order_place_after doesn't return custom product attributes in magento

Tags: magento

I try to get the products which have been bought. 
This is my code:

```
    /** @var $order Mage_Sales_Model_Order */
    $order = $eventObserver->getOrder();

    /** @var $items Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection */
    $items = $order->getItemsCollection(array(), TRUE);

    /** @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item */
    foreach($items as $item) {
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        var_dump($product->getData('language'));
    }
```

Language is a custom attribute. In this case it is empty, and I have no idea why. All default attributes, like name, id or sku are working.

This language is used as configurable attribute.

What have I to do, to get the value?

Comment: What is the input type of the attribute? Is it Text Field, Text Area,Date, Yes/No, Multiple Select or Dropdown?

Comment: It is a multiple select.

Comment: Do you get some data if you use: $product->getAttributeText('language') ?

Comment: This returns FALSE. But when I use `$product->getAttributes()` the language attribute (and the other custom attributes, which are empty) are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
When I take the product ID and load the product again:

```
$product = $item->getProduct();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load( $product->getId() );
```

I get the language as number.

Comment: Correct and for better performance check this question: "How to get specific product attribute value if i know product ID without loading whole product?" - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924226/magento-product-attribute-get-value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems()
```

Comment: When I use this, I get just the configurable products (okay, that makes sense, they the visible ones). But the configurable products doesn't contain the language. So I need to get the simple product, which has been ordered.